# Connect to Subversion Remotely

Tags: svn

I have set up subversion on one system and it works fine on that computer. I mean I can connect to svn://localhost and commit and update and ... . But I want to connect to that svn repository remotely from another system. It gives me this error :
Error: PROPFIND of '/projects/test': 504 Proxy Timeout ( The connection timed out. For more information about this event, see ISA Server Help.  ) (http://192.163.10.163)
any idea?
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Configure your firewall correctly.

Comment: thanx, I don't think its the firewall because I can see the repository from my browser using "svn://192.168.10.163/svn/test".

Comment: The svn:// protocol is not the http:// protocol. Make sure you are using the right one.

Apache + mod_dav_svn  = http://, svnserver = svn://

Comment: I have found the problem, when I want to checkout, if I type "svn://192.168.10.163/svn/test" it works, but when I put http instead of svn it doesn't work. My new problem is when I type svn://... it doesn't ask for username and password and anyone can work with svn server. how can I solve that?

Comment: edit files under your <repo>/conf folder, as mentioned in svn book:http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth

Answer (score 0):

you can check the ISA logs, but probably the svn server is not bound to the public interface on port 80 (or 443 for ssl), or it's not accepting connections from the lan... try opening the url from a browser remotely...

Comment: thanx, but how can i bound it to port 80 !?

Comment: I wrote this " svn://192.168.10.163/svn/test " in my browser and it worked, but my problem is I can't checkout using tortoise svn.